# nothing returned to variable when assigning to recursive gci search omitting folders using powershell v2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to recursively search for files on a windows 7 machine + network drives attached to it while excluding certain folders i.e. C:\windows & all recursive folders in this such as system32.

I know this question has been asked before but following the answers has not helped and I am still left with a blank variable.

Here are the combinations I have tried:

```
       $AllDrives = Get-PSDrive
      $files=@("*.xml",*.txt)


 foreach ($Drive in $AllDrives) {
if ($Drive.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem") {


$filenames = Get-ChildItem -recurse $drive.root -include ($files) -File | Where-Object {$_.PSParentPath -notlike "*Windows*" -and $_.PSParentPath -notlike "*Microsoft*"

 }

}
```

I have also tried these combinations:

```
   $filenames = Get-ChildItem -recurse $drive.root -include ($files) -File | Where-Object {$_.PSParentPath -notmatch "Program Files|Users|Windows"}



   $exclude_pattern = $drive.root + "Windows"
    $filenames = Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -path $drive.root -Include $files  -Attributes !Directory+!System -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"  | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false } | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch $exclude_pattern }
```

Unfortunately, after an amount of time has elapsed, when I type `$filename` into the terminal nothing has been assigned to it.

Comment: are you totally sure that `Get-ChildItem` on ps2 includes the parameters you are using? i cannot find any docs on that specific version of PoSh. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Also, this would error in any of your attempts `$files=@("*.xml",*.txt)` as you haven't quoted the `*.txt`

Comment: Lee is correct, there is no `-File` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` in powershell 2.0 and you should be getting an error when attempting.